# Add a WHERE clause in a complex SQL query

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I want to pass a `ShowRoomId` value to the query below. The `Employees` table has a `ShowRoomId` column.

How can I do it?

My SQL query is as following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employees A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM EmployeeBasics B
             WHERE (A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID)
             ORDER BY B.BasicUpdateDate DESC) AS B
OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT C.EmployeeId , count(*) AS TotalAbsent 
            FROM EmployeeAbsents C  
            WHERE C.AbsentDate BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-30' AND A.EmployeeID = C.EmployeeID
            GROUP BY C.EmployeeId
            ) AS C
OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT EmployeeId,
                SUM(CASE WHEN TransctionTypeId = 1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Payment, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN TransctionTypeId = 2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS RecoverSalary, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN TransctionTypeId = 3 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS RecoverCash
            FROM dbo.EmployeeAdvances D
            WHERE A.EmployeeID = D.EmployeeID
            GROUP BY EmployeeId
            ) AS D
```

Comment: Why Do You Type Every Word With Uppercase Letter? Can You Try To Add A Where Clause To The End Of Your Complex Query? It Should Work.

Comment: Yes it's Work. Thanks a lot Dear  Giorgi Nakeuri.

Comment: BTW: You are using `OUTER APPLY` kind of inappropriately. The first `OUTER APPLY` is fine; per EmployeeID you get the lastest EmployeeBasic. But the other two group by EmployeeID, which is superfluous, because you outer apply by one EmployeeID. Simply remove the `GROUP BY` clauses and the EmployeeId from the `SELECT` clauses. Or change `OUTER APPLY` to `LEFT JOIN` and move the EmployeeID comparision to the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `WHERE` clause at the end as following:

```
... YOUR SELECT ...
WHERE Col = ...YourCondition...
```

**OR**

Use `WITH` keyword to keep your current `SELECT`-statement in a `cte`. Then do your query on it.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    ... YOUR SELECT ...
)

SELECT  *
FROM    cte
WHERE   Col = ...YourCondition...
```

**OR**

You can add your `SELECT`-statement in to parentheses and name it with an allias name. So you can do query on it too.

```
SELECT  *
FROM
(
    ... YOUR SELECT ...
) t

WHERE   t.Col = ...YourCondition...
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Giorgi Nakeuri's advice, I added the `WHERE` clause at the end of the statement.

And it works for me. Revised code is here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employees A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM EmployeeBasics B
             WHERE (A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID)
             ORDER BY B.BasicUpdateDate DESC) AS B
OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT C.EmployeeId , count(*) AS TotalAbsent 
            FROM EmployeeAbsents C  
            WHERE C.AbsentDate BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-30' AND A.EmployeeID = C.EmployeeID
            GROUP BY C.EmployeeId
            ) AS C
OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT EmployeeId,
                SUM(CASE WHEN TransctionTypeId = 1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Payment, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN TransctionTypeId = 2 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS RecoverSalary, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN TransctionTypeId = 3 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS RecoverCash
            FROM dbo.EmployeeAdvances D
            WHERE A.EmployeeID = D.EmployeeID
            GROUP BY EmployeeId
            ) AS D
WHERE A.ShowRoomId = 2
```